# Displaying tabs and Input fields conditionally using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

Am working on some tabs using Jquery, if the user clicks on a specific tab,
am capturing the text of the tab clicked and displaying some input fields conditionally.
Basically when a tab is clicked the inputs should be shown,, when another tab is clicked 
the previous input should be hidden and the next shown depending on the if condition.
When I click on a tab, some input fields are shown but others fail to display off when a 
different tab is clicked

~ Kindly assist?

```js
let selected = false;
$(".columns").click(function() {
  if (!selected) {
    var subject = $(this).text();
    //alert(subject);
    if (subject.trim() == "Mathematics") {
      //Show Maths Inputs
      $('.mathInput').fadeIn(2000);
    } else if (subject == "English") {
      //Show English Inputs
      $('.engInput').fadeIn(2000);
    } else {
      $('.mathInput').css('display', 'none');
      $('.engInput').css('display', 'none');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>Mathematics</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>English</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>Swahili</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>Religious</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Maths Input-->
<div class="row mathInput" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
        <h1>Select Percentage? </h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control otherMenu wide" id="relation1">
                <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
                <option value="1"> 20% </option>
                <option value="2"> 40% </option>
                <option value="3"> 60% </option>
                <option value="4"> 70% </option>
                <option value="5"> 90% </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--END-->

<!-- English Input-->
<div class="row engInput" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
        <h1>Select Percentage? </h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control otherMenu wide" id="relation1">
                <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
                <option value="1"> 20% </option>
                <option value="2"> 40% </option>
                <option value="3"> 60% </option>
                <option value="4"> 70% </option>
                <option value="5"> 90% </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--END-->
```

Comment: can you please make a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

It is more reliable to use a specific attribute on the column class elements instead of inner text to find out which tab to show. Here is an example using a data-target attribute on the columns and a tab class on the inputs:

```js
$(".columns").click(function() {
  $(".tab").hide();
  const target = this.dataset.target
  if (target) {
    $('.' + target).fadeIn(2000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="columns" data-target="mathInput">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>Mathematics</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns" data-target="engInput">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>English</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>Swahili</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>Religious</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Maths Input-->
<div class="row tab mathInput" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
        <h1>Select Percentage? </h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control otherMenu wide" id="relation1">
                <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
                <option value="1"> 20% </option>
                <option value="2"> 40% </option>
                <option value="3"> 60% </option>
                <option value="4"> 70% </option>
                <option value="5"> 90% </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--END-->

<!-- English Input-->
<div class="row tab engInput" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
        <h1>Select Percentage? </h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control otherMenu wide" id="relation1">
                <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
                <option value="1"> 20% </option>
                <option value="2"> 40% </option>
                <option value="3"> 60% </option>
                <option value="4"> 70% </option>
                <option value="5"> 90% </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--END-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it much easier like adding some data related to the subject to inputs and when an object is selected, show those with related data and hide those with unrelated:

```js
$(".columns").click(function () {
    var subject = $(this).text().trim();
    $('[data-for]').each(function(){
        if($(this).data('for')==subject) $(this).fadeIn(2000);
        else $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>Mathematics</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>English</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>Swahili</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>

    <li class="columns">
        <label>
            <div>
                <span>Religious</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- Maths Input-->
<div class="row mathInput" style="display: none;" data-for="Mathematics">
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
    <h1>Select Percentage (math)? </h1>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control otherMenu wide" id="relation1">
            <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
            <option value="1"> 20% </option>
            <option value="2"> 40% </option>
            <option value="3"> 60% </option>
            <option value="4"> 70% </option>
            <option value="5"> 90% </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--END-->

<!-- English Input-->
<div class="row engInput" style="display: none;" data-for="English">
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
    <h1>Select Percentage (eng)? </h1>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control otherMenu wide" id="relation2">
            <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
            <option value="1"> 20% </option>
            <option value="2"> 40% </option>
            <option value="3"> 60% </option>
            <option value="4"> 70% </option>
            <option value="5"> 90% </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--END-->
```

You may also have multiple elements with the same data, and all will be visible when that subject is selected.